# Incompatible pointer type and return makes integer without a cast issue

Tags: c, pointers, casting, linked-list

I'm attempting to create a knapsack program out of the use of linked list but ive run into an issue that i can quite figure out. In nearly all of my functions im getting this error on the same line of an incompatible pointer type and i'm confused on how to fix it. The other issue im running into is a `return makes integer from pointer without a cast` errors. Full code and errors below. The error lies in the `knapsack.c` file, `test_knapsack.c` is just given for a main function example for testing purposes.

**ERRORS**

```
knapsack.c: In function ‘KnapsackRemove’:
knapsack.c:37:16: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         return NULL;
                ^
knapsack.c:47:29: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                     knapsack=(*present)->next;

knapsack.c:59:12: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     return *knapsack;
            ^
knapsack.c: In function ‘KnapsackPrint’:
knapsack.c:69:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             temp=(*temp)->next;
                 ^
knapsack.c: In function ‘KnapsackItemCount’:
knapsack.c:82:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         temp=(*temp)-> next;
             ^
knapsack.c: In function ‘KnapsackSize’:
knapsack.c:94:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         temp=(*temp)-> next;
```

**knapsack.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "knapsack.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

listitemptr KnapsackAdd(listitemptr *knapsack, int item){
    if(knapsack == NULL){
        listitemptr newer = (listitemptr)malloc(sizeof(listitemptr));
        newer-> item = item;
        newer-> count = 1;
        newer-> next = NULL;
        return newer;
    }else{
        listitemptr *temp = knapsack;
        listitemptr previous = NULL;
        while(temp!= NULL){
            if((*temp)->item == item){
                (*temp)->count=(*temp)->count+1;
                break;
            }
            previous = *temp;
            *temp = (*temp)->next;
        }
        if(temp == NULL){
            listitemptr newer = (listitemptr)malloc(sizeof(listitemptr));
            newer->item = item;
            newer->count =1;
            newer->next = NULL;
            previous->next = newer;
            return newer;
        }
        return *temp;
    }
}

int KnapsackRemove(listitemptr *knapsack, int item){
    if(knapsack==NULL)
        return NULL;
    listitemptr *present = knapsack;
    listitemptr previous = NULL;

    while(present != NULL){
        if((*present)->item == item){
            if((*present)-> count > 1){
                (*present)->count=(*present)->count-1;
            }else{
                if(previous==NULL){
                    knapsack=(*present)->next;
                }else{
                    previous->next=(*present)->next;
                    free(present);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        previous=*present;
        *present=(*present)->next;
    }

    return *knapsack;
}

void KnapsackPrint(const listitemptr *knapsack){
    if(knapsack == NULL)
        printf("(nothing)\n");
    else{
       const listitemptr *temp = knapsack;
        while(temp!= NULL){
            printf("%d (%d), ",(*temp)->item, (*temp)->count);
            temp=(*temp)->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

unsigned int KnapsackItemCount(const listitemptr *knapsack, int item){
    if(knapsack== NULL)
        return 0;
    const listitemptr *temp = knapsack;
    while(temp != NULL){
        if((*temp)-> item== item)
            return (*temp)-> count;
        temp=(*temp)-> next;
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned int KnapsackSize(const listitemptr *knapsack){
    if(knapsack == NULL)
        return 0;
   const listitemptr *temp = knapsack;
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    while(temp!= NULL){
        sum+= (*temp)-> count;
        temp=(*temp)-> next;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**knapsack.h**

```
/* knapsack.h
 * implements simple knapsack data structure as a linked list 
 * NOTE: a function may update the value of input argument *knapsack if it changes the first node of the knapsack to another node. Such a change include the case when an item is added to an empty knapsack
 */

typedef struct listitem* listitemptr;


struct listitem {
  int item;           // actual int item
  unsigned int count; // number of the same item in the knapsack; should be >= 1
  listitemptr next;   // pointer to next item 
};


listitemptr KnapsackAdd(listitemptr *knapsack, int item);


int KnapsackRemove(listitemptr *knapsack, int item);


void KnapsackPrint(const listitemptr *knapsack);


unsigned int KnapsackItemCount(const listitemptr *knapsack, int item);


unsigned int KnapsackSize(const listitemptr *knapsack);
```

**test_knapsack.c**

```
#include "knapsack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(){
   //knapsack k1
   listitemptr head=KnapsackAdd(NULL,10);
   KnapsackAdd(&head,-20);
   KnapsackAdd(&head,10);
   KnapsackAdd(&head,15);
   KnapsackAdd(&head,-20);
   KnapsackAdd(&head,10);

   KnapsackPrint(&head);

   int count=KnapsackItemCount(&head,10);
   assert(count==3);

   count=KnapsackItemCount(&head,8);
   assert(count==0);

   count=KnapsackSize(&head);
   assert(count==6);

   //knapsack2
   listitemptr head2=KnapsackAdd(NULL,5);
   KnapsackAdd(&head2,10);
   KnapsackAdd(&head2,15);
   KnapsackAdd(&head2,20);
   KnapsackAdd(&head2,-5);


   KnapsackPrint(&head2);

   KnapsackRemove(&head2,15);
   count=KnapsackSize(&head2);
   assert(count==4);

   count=KnapsackItemCount(&head2,15);
   assert(count==0);

   KnapsackRemove(&head2,10);
   count=KnapsackSize(&head2);
   assert(count==3);

   KnapsackAdd(&head,10);

   count=KnapsackSize(&head2);
   assert(count==3);

   count=KnapsackSize(&head);
   assert(count==7);   


   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/) — TL;DR, the answer is generally "No".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the line

```
temp=(*temp)->next;
```

`temp` is defined as `const listitemptr *temp`, meaning its type is `const listitemptr *`.

To find the type of `(*temp)->next`, we can look at its pieces. We already know `temp` is a `const listitemptr *`, so de-referencing it results in a `listitemptr`.

Looking at your source, we can then find the type of `next`,

```c
struct listitem {
  listitemptr next;   // pointer to next item 
};
```

now we can see that `next`, and therefore `(*temp)->next`, has the type `listitemptr`.

So you are assigning a `listitemptr` to a `const listitemptr *`.

It looks like most of these errors are caused by confusing `listitemptr` for a pointer to `listitemptr*`.

Comment: ahh okay i think i understand a bit better now where i was going wrong, but im still a little confused on how to resolve this issue without entirely rewriting my code. would deferencing temp work to solve this issue? When i attempt to do this it gives me a read-only location error

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the warning -

```
knapsack.c:37:16: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     return NULL;
```

The definition of NULL is compiler dependent, probably in your compiler `NULL` is defined as `(void*)0`, therefore you are trying to return a pointer but your function is defined as `int KnapsackRemove(...)` so it expects an int value to be returned.

Regarding -

```
knapsack.c:59:12: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 return *knapsack;
```

You are trying to return a `listitemptr` type from a function returning an int.

regarding the other warnings, you are trying to assign `listitemptr` to a `listitemptr*` type. `(*present)->next` is of type `listitemptr` and `knapsack` is of type `listitemptr*`.

Comment: It's more likely `((void *)0)`, but that's part of the problem.  And the `return *knapsack;` from a function returning an `int` requires `listitemptr` to be an `int`.

Comment: Fixed, although [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_null.htm] says ((char*)0). I wonder what compiler they looked into :)

Comment: I'm not sure which site is 'this site' … oh, you updated it: Tutorials Point doesn't have a particularly strong reputation here on SO, and this sort of thing could be a reason for that.  However, the description does say _"The C library Macro `NULL` is the value of a null pointer constant. It may be defined as `((void*)0)`, `0` or `0L` depending on the compiler vendor."_   And then also lists `((char *)0)` to confuse. Back in the days of pre-standard C (meaning the 80s or earlier), there was no `void *` type and `char *` was the universal pointer. That is, however, about 30 years out of date.

Comment: realized the mistake with the first two warnings but how would i go about fixing the last warning with `knapsack = (*present)->next` without having to break and rewrite my whole code? kinda confused on that part still but thank you for clearing that up!